# About lag of Silverlight + XNA

Tags: xna

I'm currently creating a 2D adventure game for Window Phone by using Silverlight & XNA. As I debug the codes, there are no any error. While run the game, the movement not smooth fine and seems to slow.
Is there use WCF to record the user's information and occur lagging?Or there are too many picture want to render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyze your games performance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202934(v=vs.92).aspx

Here are some ways to improve performance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh855082(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: But my game also run in Lumia 800.The problem still persists.

Comment: Try analyzing the performance of your game.  Even running on a stronger phone like the lumia 800 could be an issue for the simplest of games if not coded right.

Comment: Hi,I tried to analysis the performance of my game. It found that there are most of green area  and grey area. What should I do to avoid the problem?
Because of there are many pictures or prediction are used in my game?

Comment: What percentages are the green and grey areas?  The green indicates input processing while the grey represents background processing.

Comment: Here can't post the pictures.There are almost 100% in CPU Usage %. I am trying to change the pictures' properties to improve performance.

Comment: Take a look at the image format section in the how to improve performance link I gave you.  More specifically take a look at Dxt compression.  I guarantee that if all your images are dxt compressed you will cut your memory usage via images by AT LEAST in half.  However, the trade off is that all the images have to be sizes that are power's of 2.  You can make a non-power of 2 sized image into a power of 2 sized image via creating extra white space.  Even though the image may seem larger the compression will factor this out.

Comment: Yup~I see that.I will keep trying. If got any problem, I will looking for your help.Thanks for your information so far.

Comment: While debug the code after changing the Dxt compression and turn a power of 2 sized image, occur "Value does not fall within the expected range."
How could I solve this problem?

Comment: That does not sound like a DXT compression issue.  You may have accidentally modified your code.